# Convert column to comma separated in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two columns A and B in excel with large data.we have to consider both columns A and B, I am trying to achieve column C as output. Right now I am doing everything in excel. So I think there may a way to this in R but really don't know how to do it.Any help is appreciated..Thanks
I have

```
 Column A   ColumnB    Column C(output column)
    A1         10           A2
    A2         10           A1
    B1         3         B2,B3,B4
    B2         3         B1,B3,B4
    B3         3         B1,B2,B4
    B4         3         B1,B2,B3
    C1         6          C2,C3
    C2         6          C1,C3
    C3         6          C1,C2
```

Comment: How do you get column C from A and B? I don't understand what the process is to get to that output.

Comment: @Mako212..basically its converting column A  to Column C, by adding comma values. Column B is just to make sure it matches whatever is in Column A stays with Column A. Hope that make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

We can group by column B then find a set difference between the current column A character and the whole characters in the group:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(ColumnB) %>%
  mutate(ColumnC=map_chr(ColumnA, ~toString(setdiff(ColumnA, .x))))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   ColumnB [3]
  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC   
  <fct>     <int> <chr>     
1 A1           10 A2        
2 A2           10 A1        
3 B1            3 B2, B3, B4
4 B2            3 B1, B3, B4
5 B3            3 B1, B2, B4
6 B4            3 B1, B2, B3
7 C1            6 C2, C3    
8 C2            6 C1, C3    
9 C3            6 C1, C2
```

Comment: oh, very succinct! didn't think of referencing the group like that

Comment: I like the approach, but... why grouping by `ColumnB`?? What if it happens to have the same number for different letters? Let's say the `B`'s were 10 as well....

Comment: @CalumYou..I am getting an error..Column `ColumnC` must be length 4 (the group size) or one, not 2844

Comment: @jsingh this is something you need to mention in your post, as this is very useful information to know. :)

Comment: @AntoniosK looking at the way the data is given, the grouping can be done by ColumnB also

Comment: I thought maybe it looks like this in this small example, but in a bigger dataset we could have had same number for other letters :)

Comment: @Onyambu I am getting this error..ColumnC must be length 4 (the group size) or one, not 2844

Comment: @jsingh According to the code above, the length for each output vector is 1.. Try using `map` instead of `map_chr` to see what happens. Then you can tell where the problem lies

Comment: If you can run @Onyambu 's example fine but you cannot run your full dataset then you have to find out what is the difference between your dataset and the small dataset you posted. Does your full dataset have 2844 rows by any chance?

Comment: @AntoniosK..yes I have 2844 rows in actual data..but I am not understanding the error

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the question is phrased very clearly but I am interpreting the desired results to be that you want Column C to have all the values from each group of Column B, leaving out the value of Column A. You can do this as follows:

1. `nest` Column A and join it back onto the original data frame
2. `flatten` it so you now have a vector of the Column A values
3. use `setdiff` to get the values that are not Column A
4. collapse into comma separated string with `str_c`

You can see that your desired Column C is reproduced.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- structure(list(ColumnA = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "C1", "C2", "C3"), ColumnB = c(10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L), ColumnC = c("A2", "A1", "B2,B3,B4", "B1,B3,B4", "B1,B2,B4", "B1,B2,B3", "C2,C3", "C1,C3", "C1,C2")), problems = structure(list(row = 9L, col = "ColumnC", expected = "", actual = "embedded null", file = "literal data"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(ColumnA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), ColumnB = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), ColumnC = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))

tbl %>%
  left_join(
    tbl %>% select(-ColumnC) %>% nest(ColumnA)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    data = flatten(data),
    output = map2(data, ColumnA, ~ setdiff(.x, .y)),
    output = map_chr(output, ~ str_c(., collapse = ","))
    )
#> Joining, by = "ColumnB"
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC  data      output  
#>   <chr>     <int> <chr>    <list>    <chr>   
#> 1 A1           10 A2       <chr [2]> A2      
#> 2 A2           10 A1       <chr [2]> A1      
#> 3 B1            3 B2,B3,B4 <chr [4]> B2,B3,B4
#> 4 B2            3 B1,B3,B4 <chr [4]> B1,B3,B4
#> 5 B3            3 B1,B2,B4 <chr [4]> B1,B2,B4
#> 6 B4            3 B1,B2,B3 <chr [4]> B1,B2,B3
#> 7 C1            6 C2,C3    <chr [3]> C2,C3   
#> 8 C2            6 C1,C3    <chr [3]> C1,C3   
#> 9 C3            6 C1,C2    <chr [3]> C1,C2
```

Created on 2018-08-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

```
df = read.table(text = "
ColumnA   ColumnB   
A1         10          
A2         10          
B1         3        
B2         3        
B3         3        
B4         3        
C1         6        
C2         6        
C3         6        
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ColumnB) %>%                                         # for each ColumnB value
  mutate(vals = list(ColumnA),                                  # create a list of all Column A values for each row
         vals = map2(vals, ColumnA, ~.x[.x != .y]),             # exclude the value in Column A from that list
         vals = map_chr(vals, ~paste0(.x, collapse = ","))) %>% # combine remaining values in the list                                        
  ungroup()                                                     # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   ColumnA ColumnB vals    
#   <chr>     <int> <chr>   
# 1 A1           10 A2      
# 2 A2           10 A1      
# 3 B1            3 B2,B3,B4
# 4 B2            3 B1,B3,B4
# 5 B3            3 B1,B2,B4
# 6 B4            3 B1,B2,B3
# 7 C1            6 C2,C3   
# 8 C2            6 C1,C3   
# 9 C3            6 C1,C2
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is to find all OTHER entries of column A that share the current value of column B

Grouping by B, and finding all A's associated with the value should do the trick (some clean-up afterward removes the current entry of A from the resulting column C)

```
a <- c("a1", "a2","b1", "b2","b3", "b4","c1","c2","c3","d1")

b <- c(10,10,3,3,3,3,6,6,6,5)

dta <- data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors = F)

dta<-dta %>% 
group_by(b) %>% 
mutate(c = paste0(a,collapse = ",")) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
mutate(c = str_replace(c,pattern = paste0(",",a),replacement = "")) %>% 
mutate(c = str_replace(c,pattern = paste0(a,","),replacement = "")) %>% 
mutate(c = ifelse(c==a,NA,c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version of `tidyverse` solution. The `separate` function is handy to separate an existing column to new columns. By doing this, we can create the `Group` column to make sure all the operation would be within each group. `map2` and `map` function are ideal to do vectorized operation. `dat2` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  separate(ColumnA, into = c("Group", "Number"), remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE, sep = 1) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(List = list(ColumnA)) %>%
  mutate(List = map2(List, ColumnA, ~.x[!(.x %in% .y)])) %>%
  mutate(ColumnC = map_chr(List, ~str_c(.x, collapse = ","))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(starts_with("Column"))
dat2
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC 
#   <chr>     <int> <chr>   
# 1 A1           10 A2      
# 2 A2           10 A1      
# 3 B1            3 B2,B3,B4
# 4 B2            3 B1,B3,B4
# 5 B3            3 B1,B2,B4
# 6 B4            3 B1,B2,B3
# 7 C1            6 C2,C3   
# 8 C2            6 C1,C3   
# 9 C3            6 C1,C2
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ColumnA   ColumnB
    A1         10 
                  A2         10 
                  B1         3
                  B2         3
                  B3         3
                  B4         3
                  C1         6
                  C2         6
                  C3         6",
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```